# html element - property of document object ? or an object?

Tags: javascript

so,  html elements such as `<title>`are sometimes referred as property,  but sometimes they are referred as objects. i am kinda confused.  are html elements properties of document object? or are they objects? or are they both at the same time?  thanks.       to make question meet quality standards i will add some random codes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you need this information ? Do you want to use it in Jquery?

Comment: just starting to learn DOM, and javascript, it kinda bothers me when i dont get something :D

Comment: sometimes properties _are_ objects: {a:{b:1}}... did i blow your mind?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you are referring to. Look at it this way. Before teh dom is parsed, `<tite>Hello!</title>` is a tag. After the DOM is parsed, it will be an element that is a `childNode` of the `<html>` node, which is part of `document`. The text content of the title element will also be set as the value of `document.title` (`title` being a property of `document`.) So, to answer your question.... **Yes, Yes, and Yes**

Comment: `document.title` is basically an internal shortcut to `document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].textContent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document object has a title property, which is a string, which is an object. But the document object does not have direct properties for the html elements in the page, that's why you have accessor functions like document.getElementById('id'), which return objects representing html elements. Open up a console in chrome and type document. to see all the properties the document object has. Also see that document.title and document.getElementByTagName('title')[0] do not return the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The document itself is a document node.
    All HTML elements are element nodes.
    All HTML attributes are attribute nodes.
    Text inside HTML elements are text nodes.
    Comments are comment nodes.
    In the HTML DOM, the Element object represents an HTML element.

[DOM w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)

Answer (score 0):

They are two separate things.
Element is the HTML element or tag. 
Javascript and jQuery (which is also Javascript), for example, modify and control the HTML elements by using the HTML DOM (HTML Document Object Model). The DOM contains the Objects you're referring to. Each DOM object refers to an element and when the Javascript modifies your HTML page, it's actually accessing the DOM, not the HTML elements.

Take a look at: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html.

Answer (score 0):

The DOM, or Document Object Model is a tree. The HTML `document` available at `window.document` is the root node of this tree.

Essentially everything else in the document is a node somewhere in this tree, whether it is an element like `<p>` or an attribute node like `class="foo"` or a text node. Each of these nodes are objects that you can interact with via Javascript.